# how to print only distinct line and remove duplicate line

Tags: c#

I'm getting lines by reading pdf file and i want just print `distinct` line .Here is my code

**aspx.cs**

```
for (int i = 1; i <= intPageNum; i++)
{
    string text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, new LocationTextExtractionStrategy());
    words = text.Split('\n');
    for (int ii = 0; ii < langu.Count; ii++)
    {
        for (int j = 0, len = words.Length; j < len; j++)
        {
            line = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(words[j]));
            if (line.Contains(langu[ii].InnerXml))
            {
                Response.Write(line+ "</br>");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

line contains duplicate `lines` but i want just  write `distinct` lines.how can i do this?Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume by `distinct` you mean that you only want to print the each line once.

I'd probably use a generic `List` of `string` to hold the values I already output and ensure that I only output each line once.  Something along these lines:

```
// Declaration outside your for loops
List<string> ExistingLines = new List<string>();
...
        line = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(words[j]));
        if (line.Contains(langu[ii].InnerXml) && !ExistingLines.Contains(line))
        {
            Response.Write(line+ "</br>");
            ExistingLines.Add(line);
        }
....
```

What this code effectively does is allows you to keep a track of existing lines by adding each distinct line to the `List`.  If a later line does not match an earlier one (`!ExistingLines.Contains(line)`) it will be added.

Comment: let me check please

Comment: here i m getting error near `List<string();` and here is line `List<string> ExistingLines = new List<string();`

Comment: You are missing the `>` after `string`... Surely you could spot the mistake for yourself there?

Comment: ouhh great man  ! Thanks alot.Now i'm getting distinct lines.thankssss